# The python's argparse errors

Tags: python, namespaces, argparse

where report this error : TypeError: 'Namespace' object is not iterable

```
import argparse

def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=True)
    parser.add_argument('-a', '--aa', action="store_true", default=False)
    parser.add_argument('-b', action="store", dest="b")
    parser.add_argument('-c', action="store", dest="c", type=int)

    return parser.parse_args()

def main():
    (options, args) = parse_args()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Before opening a question you should at least skim through the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) of a module/package. In particular the *first* [example](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#example) of usage clearly shows that you should do `args = parser.parse_args()` instead of `options, args = parser.parse_args()` as you would do with older modules.

Answer (score 14):

Your issue has to do with this line:

```
(options, args) = parse_args()
```

Which seems to be an idiom from the deprecated "optparse".

Use the argparse idiom without "options":

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Do Stuff')
parser.add_argument('--verbosity')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
args = parse_args()
print args
```

Results:

```
$ python x.py -b B -aa
Namespace(aa=True, b='B', c=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly like the error message says: `parser.parse_args()` returns a `Namespace` object, which is `not iterable`. Only iterable things can be 'unpacked' like `options, args = ...`.

Though I have no idea what you were expecting `options` and `args`, respectively, to end up as in your example.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in that parse_argv option is not required or used, only argv is passed.

Insted of:

```
(options, args) = parse_args()
```

You need to pass

```
args = parse_args()
```

And the rest remains same.
For calling any method just make sure of using argv instead of option.

For example:

```
a = argv.b
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way (for me) to operate on args, where `args = parser.parse_args()`
is using `args.__dict__`. It's good, for example, when you want to edit arguments.
Moreover, it's appropriate to use long notation in your arguments, for example `'--second'` in `'-a'` and `'--third'` in `'-b'`, as in first argument.

If you want to run 'main' you can should miss 'options', but it was said earlier.